# Reduce length of specific column in delimited text file

Tags: text-processing, scripting, columns

I need for the 5th column in a delimited text file to be reduced to just the first 5 characters. All other columns must remain unedited.

Input:

```
file1.txt    column1      column2      column3     column4      column5
123456789    123456789    123456789   123456789    123456789
```

I would like the output to look like:

```
output.txt    column1      column2      column3     column4      column5
123456789    123456789    123456789   123456789    12345
```

Note: I happen to use commas as the delimiter.

Comment: This doesn't look like a CSV file as commas/semicolons are missing. Are those tabs between the values?. Can this table have quoted values with newlines like a CSV file? In general you cannot use text-processing tools on CSV, you need a real parser except for not so realistic simple cases. Never more than 5 columns? If not what about alignment?

Comment: I can change the delimiter to whatever is needed.  I just typically use commas.  The example I provided is obviously just a visual representation of what I am looking for, not an actual CSV.  If it would make the question easier, I could easily update the table, but I guess I assumed someone would have a quick command off the top of their head.

Comment: For real CSV files, you need to use Perl or Python with an appropriate library, otherwise you'll break the file. If this is a simple subset of CSV (no quoted values, no newlines in values, etc.) you should clearly indicate that, then simpler solutions with awk/sed etc can be given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `file.csv` looks like this:

```
123456789,123456789,123456789,123456789,123456789
123456789,123456789,123456789,123456789,223456789
123456789,123456789,123456789,123456789,323456789
123456789,123456789,123456789,123456789,423456789
```

Then, you can do:

```
$ awk -F, '{print $1","$2","$3","$4","substr($5,1,5) }' file.csv
123456789,123456789,123456789,123456789,12345
123456789,123456789,123456789,123456789,22345
123456789,123456789,123456789,123456789,32345
123456789,123456789,123456789,123456789,42345
```

Comment: You can do it more portable `awk -F, -v OFS="," '{$5=substr($5,1,5)}1'`

Comment: To pass 1 line with headers just modify `awk -F, -v OFS="," 'NR>1{$5=substr($5,1,5)}1'`

Answer (score 1):

If all the values are simple (no quotes and newlines in a value) and if they are comma separated, like:

```
123456789,123456789,123456789,123456789,123456789
```

and if there are always 5 such values on a line, you can use `sed`:

```
sed '2,$s/\(.*\),\(.*\),\(.*\),\(.*\),\(.....\)\(.*\)/\1,\2,\3,\4,\5/' input
```

The `2,$` assumes you have a header that is comma separated as well (and that its
fifth column should not be truncated), if that is not the case leave it out.

Comment: If all first columns have fields more then 5 symbol length you can make script more portable `sed 's/\([^,]\{5\}\)[^,]*/\1/5' < input`

Comment: To edit above variant to work with any length fields `sed '2,$ s/\([^,]\{,5\}\)[^,]*/\1/5' < input`

Answer (score 1):

Or `awk`:

For white-space delimited:

```
awk 'NR==1 { print; next} {print $1, $2, $3, $4, substr($5,1,5)}'
```

For comma delimited:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=","} NR==1 { print; next} {print $1, $2, $3, $4, substr($5,1,5)}'
```

For slightly better CSV splitting and assuming GNU awk:

```
awk -vFPAT='[^,]*|"[^"]*"'  'NR==1 { print; next} {print $1, $2, $3, $4, substr($5,1,5)}'
```